# ERROR IFS expects all arguments after position 0

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to reference a cell depending on a value, but when I use the following code, I get an #N/A error with the note IFS expects all arguments after position 0 to be in pairs.

=IFS(OR(MONTH(TODAY())=-1,MONTH(TODAY())=4),IFS(I10=true, " Completed", A10="NOT STARTED","⛔ Not Started", L10=3/9,"  On Track",L10=2/9,"  On Track",J19=1/9,"  On Track",L10<2/9,"   At Risk",),MONTH(TODAY())=5,IFS(I10=true, " Completed",A10="NOT STARTED","⛔ Not Started",L11=3/9,"  On Track",L11=2/9,"  On Track",L11<2/9,"   At Risk"),MONTH(TODAY())=6,IFS(I10=true, " Completed",A10="NOT STARTED","⛔ Not Started",L12=3/9,"  On Track",L12=2/9,"  On Track",L12<2/9,"   At Risk"))

Answer (score 1):

Your formula probably has an extra trailing comma in `L10<2/9," At Risk",` or perhaps it is missing the default values from each `ifs()`. Try this:

```
=ifs(
  or(month(today()) = -1, month(today()) = 4),
    ifs( 
      I10 = true, " Completed", 
      A10 = "NOT STARTED", "⛔ Not Started", 
      L10 = 3/9, " On Track", 
      L10 = 2/9, " On Track", 
      J19 = 1/9, " On Track", 
      L10 < 2/9, " At Risk", 
      true, na() 
    ), 
  month(today()) = 5, 
    ifs( 
      I10 = true, " Completed", 
      A10 = "NOT STARTED", "⛔ Not Started", 
      L11 = 3/9, " On Track", 
      L11 = 2/9, " On Track", 
      L11 < 2/9, " At Risk", 
      true, na() 
    ), 
  month(today()) = 6, 
    ifs( 
      I10 = true, " Completed", 
      A10 = "NOT STARTED", "⛔ Not Started", 
      L12 = 3/9, " On Track", 
      L12 = 2/9, " On Track", 
      L12 < 2/9, " At Risk", 
      true, na() 
    ) 
)
```

I could not quite decipher why the first `or()` has a test for `month(today()) = -1`. I do not think that will ever evaluate to `true`.